# How to get this summation in closed form?

Tags: calculus, summation

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \left( \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{k^{2}}{n}\right)$$

How would one go about putting a summation in closed form if the lower limit is 0 instead of 1? I know you can't immediately use the summation formulas.

Comment: What do you mean? The lower limit is already $0$

Comment: For the formatting, have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \left( \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{k^{2}}{n}\right) \\
= & \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{k^{2}}{n} \\
= & \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n} + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{n}}_{n+1 \text{ times}} - \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} k^{2} \\
= & 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}- \dfrac{1}{n} \times \dfrac{n (n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}\\
= & 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} \\
= & \dfrac{-2n^{3} - 3n^{2} + 5n + 6}{6n}
\end{align}

See [this](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm) for the details about the squared sum of first $k$ natural numbers.

Here is a solution by Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the 1 in the final answer?

Comment: You need to correct the $k=0$ below the $\sum$ to read $k=1$.  If you want $n$ terms.  As it stands, you have $n+1$ terms.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It can be factored:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \biggl( \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{k^{2}}{n}\biggr)&=\frac 1n  \biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^{n}1-\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k^2\biggr)=\frac1n\biggl(n+1-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\biggr)\\[1ex]
&=\frac{(n+1)(-2n^2-n+6)}{6n}.
\end{align}
Now  the polynomial $\;2n^2+n-6$ has an integer root: $-2$ and the product of the roots is $\dfrac{6}{-2}=-3$, so the other root is $\dfrac32$, and we have a factorisation:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \biggl( \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{k^{2}}{n}\biggr)=
-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n-3)}{6n}.$$